# Sorting by newest date in joined query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in MSSQL that needs modification but I am unable to get it working properly. The query now is the following:

```
SELECT Computer.Id AS ComputerId, 
        Concat(HardDisk.Id, ' ') disks
        FROM Computer 
        LEFT JOIN HardDisk ON Computer.Id = HardDisk.ComputerId 
        LEFT JOIN DiskOperationLog ON DiskOperationLog.HardDiskId = HardDisk.Id
```

I need it to also check in the table DiskOperationLog for an EndTime column and if two DiskOperationLog columns with the same HardDisk.Id exists it only needs to select the DiskOperationLog with the newest date. Is this something you can do? I suspect it can be done using the max(DiskOperationLog.EndTime) but I am unable to get it properly included in my selection.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

> I need it to also check in the table DiskOperationLog for an EndTime column and if two DiskOperationLog columns with the same HardDisk.Id exists it only needs to select the DiskOperationLog with the newest date.

Your query doesn't seem to use `DiskOperationLog` -- not for filtering (the query uses `LEFT JOIN`) and not selecting any columns.  Let me assume this is an oversight in the question.

In SQL Server, the simplest method to do what you want uses `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT c.Id AS ComputerId, Concat(hd.Id, ' ') disks
FROM Computer c LEFT JOIN
     HardDisk hd
     ON c.Id = hd.ComputerId OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) dol.*
      FROM DiskOperationLog dol
      WHERE dol.HardDiskId = hd.Id
      ORDER BY dol.EndTime DESC
     ) dol;
```

`APPLY` implements a *lateral join* whihc is a lot like a correlated subquery, with the following differences:

- The logic is in the `FROM` clause.
- More than one column can be returned.
- More than one row can be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ROW_NUMBER() clause. You would want to partition by HardDisk.Id and order by DiskOperationLog.EndTime descending.

```
With Qry1 As (
    SELECT      Computer.Id AS ComputerId, 
                Concat(HardDisk.Id, ' ') disks,
                DiskOperationLog.EndTime,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HardDisk.Id ORDER BY DiskOperationLog.EndTime DESC) As Seq
    FROM        Computer 
    LEFT JOIN   HardDisk 
    ON          Computer.Id = HardDisk.ComputerId 
    LEFT JOIN   DiskOperationLog 
    ON          DiskOperationLog.HardDiskId = HardDisk.Id
)
SELECT      Computer.Id AS ComputerId, 
            Concat(HardDisk.Id, ' ') disks,
            DiskOperationLog.EndTime,
FROM        Qry1
WHERE       Seq = 1
```

BTW, if you're trying to get a list of comma-separated disk numbers in column #2, that is definitely not the way to do it.